# What is the abscissa of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac {1} {n^s}\ $?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

> What is the abscissa of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac {1} {n^s}\ $?

In the lecture note our instructor claimed that the abscissa of convergence of the above series is $0.$ It is a well-known fact  that the abscissa of convergence of the zeta function is $1$ and hence the abscissa of absolute convergence of the alternating zeta function is also equal to $1.$ But I don't have any idea about it's abscissa of convergence. Is there any result related to that?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: This is an alternating series.  Perhaps try the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: We need a real number $r$ such that the given series converges on $\{z\ |\ \mathfrak {R} (z) \gt r \}$ and diverges on $\{z\ |\ \mathfrak {R} (z) \lt r \}.$ Am I right @Eric Towers? Now how does Leibnitz test help?

Comment: While you are correct, this in no way changes my first comment.

Comment: @Eric Towers I haven't used Leibnitz test when the exponents are complex numbers. I think it can be similarly used because $n^{z} = n^{\mathfrak {R} (z) + i\ \mathfrak {I} (z)} = n^{\mathfrak {R} (z)} n^{i\ \mathfrak {I} (z)}.$ Now if $\mathfrak {R} (z) \gt 0$ then the first term goes to $0$ and the second term is bounded by $1$ and hence the product also goes to zero. Then we can apply alternating series test. But I am not quite sure how do we deal decreasing sequence of complex numbers as we all know complex number system is not well-ordered.

Comment: @Eric Towers another fact is that alternating series deals with positive and negative numbers but in our case all of them are replaced by complex numbers.

Comment: $|n^{-s}| \leq |n^{\Re (-s)}|$.  So convergence for an $s \in \Bbb{R}$ implies convergence on the entire abscissa containing $s$.

Comment: @Eric Towers you have considered absolute convergence. Instead I want convergence. I don't understand your logic at all. How do we apply alternating series test here? If your argument rigorous enough then could you please post it as an official answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Towers I actually want to know how does the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^{\mathfrak {R} (s)}}$ guarantee the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^s}.$

Comment: This is a general result about Dirichlet series and follows from summation by parts and an integral trick

Comment: Could you please answer my question or at least provide me some link where I can read it?

Comment: the wikipedia link for the Dirichlet series is a good start; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence